# Is it bad practice to test for reachibility this way?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Is it bad practice to test for reachibility of a web service by using a NSURLConnection call on a certain method that returns YES if the connection exists?

I looked at other ways of doing it but couldn't figure out ho to test if the specific service is available rather than WiFI or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `SCNetworkReachability` (see [Apple's *Reachability* sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)) but that only checks whether a server should be reachable, it doesn't tell you whether a service is actually available (running). For that you do have to try to use it. Just make sure to *not* use `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` on the main thread as that is synchronously and will block the thread until it's done. If you do that on the main thread the UI will freeze until either the service has responded or timed out. So either use the asynchronous methods of `NSURLConnection` (the "recommended" way) or use the synchronous method on a separate thread. The former is easier/better in my opinion.

Comment: Interesting! Although it's actually called 'SCNetworkReachability' - just fixing the name for better searchability.. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It's the **only** way to do it reliably.  Although, the service's status can change between you doing the test and trying to get real data, so you have to code your real connections as if you hadn't already checked, so then why bother with a separate check?